# Dropdown list doesnt want country drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a three dropdowns for Country, State, and City. But I want only State and country dropdown. Because Country is only One. So no need of Country dropdown. I tried but there were  some classes which were giving error. Please help. See the code for your reference.

```
var countries = _careerHelper.GetCountries();
countries.Insert(0, "--Select--");
ddlCountry.DataSource = countries;
ddlCountry.DataBind();

var states = _careerHelper.GetStates(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
states.Insert(0, "--Select--");
ddlState.DataSource = states;
ddlState.DataBind();

var cities = _careerHelper.GetLocations(ddlCountry.SelectedValue, ddlState.SelectedValue);
cities.Insert(0, "--Select--");
ddlCity.DataSource = cities;
ddlCity.DataBind();
```

_careerhelper class code is below:-

```
public List<string> GetCountries()
{
    return _rblDataContext.Locations
                          .Select(m => m.CountryName)
                          .Distinct()
                          .ToList();
}

public List<string> GetStates(string country)
{
    if (country == "")
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return _rblDataContext.Locations
                              .Where(m => m.CountryName.ToLower() == country
                              .ToLower())
                              .Select(m => m.StateName)
                              .Distinct()
                              .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know how to remove the country dropdown so I can manage the things with State and City dropdown. Please help

Comment: It's pretty straight-forward from the looks of it. Just don't pass country around as a parameter.. o_O

Comment: @SpaceBison: I just want to remove the country dropdown. Is there any way. Because Country dropdown has only one value so it is of no use.

Comment: var country = "Christmas Island"; - pass that around instead of ddlWhatever.Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

Here you are using Country dropdown to pass selected country as parameter.

```
var states = _careerHelper.GetStates(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
```

**Solution 1:**

Just manually set the country name and pass it into `GetStates` as **SpaceBison** suggested.

```
string country = "Country Name";
var states = _careerHelper.GetStates(country);
```

Same thing you will have to do with the `Cities` as well:

```
var cities = _careerHelper.GetLocations(country, ddlState.SelectedValue);
```

**Solution 2:**

The other solution is to just set default value into the dropdown and let everything as it is.

Select the country and disable the dropdown so user can not choose it.

```
ddlCountry.Items.FindByText("India").Selected = true;
ddlCountry.Enabled = false;
```

Complete code solution:

```
//populate countries
var countries = _careerHelper.GetCountries();
countries.Insert(0, "--Select--");
ddlCountry.DataSource = countries;
ddlCountry.DataBind();

//select default country
ddlCountry.Items.FindByText("India").Selected = true;
ddlCountry.Enabled = false;

//populate states
var states = _careerHelper.GetStates(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);
states.Insert(0, "--Select--");
ddlState.DataSource = states;
ddlState.DataBind();

//populate cities
var cities = _careerHelper.GetLocations(ddlCountry.SelectedValue, ddlState.SelectedValue);
cities.Insert(0, "--Select--");
ddlCity.DataSource = cities;
ddlCity.DataBind();
```

Comment: What changes need to be done on cs class ? to pull the data
ie: _careerHelper class. Need to comment out country method ??
and what else, please help

Comment: can we set the country dropdown to only India, and get postback for states. Please help.

Comment: Yes you can do it. I update the answer to guide you

Comment: i did it, but I am getting like I then N then D like this in Country dropdown and also state dropdown is also not populating.

Comment: Now the data is coming, in the selection of I of Country dropdown, but when I select any state, it again moves to the Select value.

Comment: I could not get your problem. Can you explain with an image? and one more thing, do not put the code into `form load` event. Put it where it was before.

Comment: Please see the image in below link: http://s1255.photobucket.com/user/nadeemkhn157/library/ I will also share the CS code for your reference.

Comment: Also please see the code in the link mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/r3Pz4/1/

Comment: What does the `btnChangeValue` button do?

Comment: It is hidden, but I think it has something to do with the changing of value of dropdown, It was coded before. so couldn't have that much idea of it. Please help

Comment: ddlCountry.Items.FindByText("India").Selected = true; is giving me  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Actually the problem is your country dropdown is not populating properly. I think it is the data issue. or may be the LINQ query is not properly written (I can not correct it cause I've not much used LINQ queries). Now what you have to do is to set the break points and check for data which is coming to populate dropdown list. and use `ddlCountry.SelectedValue = country;` instead of `ddlCountry.Items.FindByText("India").Selected = true;` line.

Comment: I did like this and it was working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/r3Pz4/3/  Thanks a lot Shaharyar bhai. My name is Nadeem.

Comment: You've got a really good name. Why did you like **user3751568** more than that?

Comment: It was by default when I created the Account. Will change it. Thanks for helping me out :)